# SQL server - Row_Number returning incorrect values for 1 row

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 SQL tables (log and Transaction) based on these 2 tables I want to print the final result which will have a combinational result. But for 1 row I am not getting the expected output using the below query.

```
 ;WITH MyCte AS 
(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY tbl.tablename
      ORDER BY l.moment 
   ) row_num
,tbl.tablename, l.moment, l.root_pid ,l.origin + ' - ' + l.message AS ErrorMessage
from dbo.log l
left join dbo.transaction_tbl tbl
on l.root_pid = tbl.rootpid and tbl.errormessage  not in (' - ')
 )

  
SELECT  *
FROM    MyCte
WHERE   row_num =1
```

[image: Queries_Result]

[image: ExpectedOutput]

**UPDATE**

```
create table dbo.log
(
   pid varchar(50),
   root_pid varchar(50),
   moment datetime,
   origin varchar(50),
   message varchar(max)
)

insert into dbo.log (pid,root_pid,moment,origin,message)
values ('abc','20200101_abc','2020-01-01 12:00:00.123','tjava1','connection issue'),
('xyz','20200220_xyz','2020-02-20 13:00:00.134','tmsqlinput1','parse excpetion'),
('lmp','20200220_xyz','2020-02-20 16:00:00.134','tmsqlinput2','parse excpetion'),
('mlp','20200320_mlp','2020-03-20 14:00:00.120','tmsqlinput2','parse excpetion')


create table dbo.transaction_tbl
(
   tablename varchar(50),
   Sourceid varchar(50),
   rootpid varchar(50),
   startdatetime datetime,
   errormessage varchar(max),
   status varchar(50)
)

insert into dbo.transaction_tbl (tablename,Sourceid,rootpid,startdatetime,errormessage,status)
values 
('Account','1','20200220_xyz','2020-02-20 13:12:00.133','tmsqlinput1-parse excpetion','fail'),
('GoLive','1','20200220_xyz','2020-02-20 15:12:00.133',' - ','Success'),
('Case','1','20200220_xyz','2020-02-20 16:12:00.133','tmsqlinput2-parse excpetion','fail'),
('Contact','1','20200320_mlp','2020-03-20 14:15:00.120','tmsqlinput2-parse excpetion','fail')
```

Comment: Images of data don't help us help you. Take the time to post a [mre] so we can replicate the problem and correct it.

Comment: @Larnu I have updated my post. Please check the UPDATE Section of my post.

Comment: @shawnt00 That didn't help either, it simply printed incorrect moment value for Row1 (Account) instead of Row3 (Case)

Comment: Wait, is this not simply because you have `ORDER BY l.moment` when it should be `ORDER BY l.moment DESC`; emphasis on the **DESC**. The SQL is returning the correct rows for what you've written, as it returns the  **oldest** row.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to do about the "null" table: `tbl.errormessage like l.origin + '%'` will connect origin to the text in the error message and return what you need in the other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the relationship between these tables but adding a join condition to match `origin` against the `errormessage` would give you the desired result.

```
on l.root_pid = tbl.rootpid and tbl.errormessage not in (' - ')
    and tbl.errormessage like l.origin + '%'
```

The added condition also seems to make the other `errormessage` filter redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Your join between `log` and `transaction_tbl` is a `left join`, meaning that the query will still return rows *and row numbers* independently of whether the errormessage was `-`. Therefore each `tablename` from the transaction table will have a row with number `1`.

You final select takes rows with row number `1` and joins them just on root process id (`l.root_pid = tbl.rootpid`). These two conditions (row number / process id) are not connected...

A `outer apply` could fix this.

```
select tbl.tablename,
       l.moment,
       l.root_pid,
       l.origin + ' - ' + l.message AS ErrorMessage
from dbo.log l
outer apply (   select top 1 tbl.tablename
                from dbo.transaction_tbl tbl
                where tbl.rootpid = l.root_pid         -- link process id ...
                  and tbl.startdatetime >= l.moment
                  and tbl.errormessage not in (' - ')
                order by tbl.startdatetime ) tbl;      -- ... and timing in one query
```

To see it in action: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=24d4fa450c980ddb93571e1336a57f08) (thanks for sample data!).

Comment: Thanks, @Sander Moment column values are printed correctly, but if you see the expected result which I have attached. In the first column (tablename)  value is repeated for Account it should be Case

Answer (score 0):

DATETIME datatype (which I think you used) as a lack of precision (3 ms). So some rows can derivate from the initial value.
It is the reason that with the 2008 version MS has bring the DATETIME2 datatype to use instaed of DATETIME !

If the datetime participate as a PK, use:

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET DTATEIME_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION ON;
```

To try to correct the problem....

Comment: `datetime` and `datetime2` don't have different ordering though. For both a `datetime` and `datetime2` the value `2020-02-20T16:00:00.133` is *greater than* `2020-02-20T13:00:00.133`. Suspect the value the OP wants is being not being brought back in a `JOIN`, or perhaps it's not actually a date and time data type.

Answer (score 0):

Demo about the supposed ordering...

```
DECLARE @DT TABLE (DT_INSERT_STR_VALUE CHAR(25), DT DATETIME); 
DECLARE @DT2 TABLE (DT2_INSERT_STR_VALUE CHAR(25), DT2 DATETIME2(3))

INSERT INTO @DT2 VALUES
('2000-01-01 00:00:00.002', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.002'),
('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
('2000-01-01 00:00:00.001', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.001'),
('2000-01-01 00:00:00.003', '2000-01-01 00:00:00.003');

INSERT INTO @DT SELECT * FROM @DT2;

SELECT *
FROM   @DT AS T1 FULL OUTER JOIN @DT2 AS T2 
       ON T1.DT = T2.DT2
ORDER BY DT
```

the result is :

```
DT_INSERT_STR_VALUE       DT                      DT2_INSERT_STR_VALUE      DT2
------------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------- ---------------------------
NULL                      NULL                    2000-01-01 00:00:00.002   2000-01-01 00:00:00.002
NULL                      NULL                    2000-01-01 00:00:00.001   2000-01-01 00:00:00.001
NULL                      NULL                    2000-01-01 00:00:00.003   2000-01-01 00:00:00.003
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000   2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000   2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
2000-01-01 00:00:00.001   2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000   2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
2000-01-01 00:00:00.003   2000-01-01 00:00:00.003 NULL                      NULL
2000-01-01 00:00:00.002   2000-01-01 00:00:00.003 NULL                      NULL
```

Comparing two different type of data may give some haphazard order